# Regular expression Capture and Backrefence

Tags: regex, perl

Here's the string I'm searching.

```
T+4ACCGT+12CAAGTACTACCGT+12CAAGTACTACCGT+4ACCGA+6CTACCGT+12CAAGTACTACCGT+12CAAGTACTACCG
```

I want to capture the digits behind the number for X digits (X being the previous number) I also want to capture the complete string.

ie the capture should return:

```
+4ACCG
+12AAGTACTACCGT
etc.
```

and :

```
ACCG
AAGTACTACCGT
etc.
```

Here's the regex I'm using:

```
(\+(\d+)([ATGCatgcnN]){\2});
```

and I'm using $1 and $3 for the captures.

What am I missing ?

Comment: I don't understand at all what you want. Please elaborate with several examples so I can maybe figure it out

Comment: What mean the N in your character class?

Comment: It means the character N.

Comment: @dstorey: A->adenine C->cythosine T->Thymine G->Guanine N->?

Comment: Not to be a smart ass , but if you've surmised that much you should know that N is any of the bases

Comment: @dstorey I didn't figure out `N`, either. I recognized GATC but had to look up what they stood for. I'm more familiar with strings (computers, not physics) than biology. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop works because the `\G` assertion tells the regex engine to begin the search after the last match , (digit(s)), in the string.

```
$_ = 'T+4ACCGT+12CAAGTACTACCGT+12CAAGTACTACCGT+4ACCGA+6CTACCGT+12CAAGTACTACCGT+12CAAGTACTACCG';

while (/(\d+)/g) {
    my $dig = $1;
    /\G([TAGCN]{$dig})/i;
    say $1;
}
```

The results are

```
ACCG
CAAGTACTACCG
CAAGTACTACCG
ACCG
CTACCG
CAAGTACTACCG
CAAGTACTACCG
```

I think this is correct but not sure  :-|

**Update:** Added the `\G` assertion which tells the regex to begin immediately after the last matched number.

Comment: Perfect, I'll implement this today.

Comment: Good. Glad I was able to help  :-)

Comment: Just an FYI - re-using $1 doesn't work. 
`code
while ($base_string =~ /\+(\d+)/ig){

  my $dig = $1;

  if ($base_string=~/\G([TAGCN]{$dig})/i){

    print "$dig\t".$1 ."\n";

   }
  
  }`

Answer (score 3):

**You can not use a backreference in a quantifier**. `\1` is a instruction to match what `$1` contains, so `{\1}` is not a valid quantifier. But why do you need to match the exact number? Just match the letters (because the next part starts again with a `+`).

So try:

```
(\+\d+([ATGCatgcnN]+));
```

and find the complete match in `$1` and the letters in `$2`

Another problem in your regex is that your quantifier is outside your third capturing group. That way only the last letter would be in the capturing group. Place the quantifier inside the group to capture the whole sequence.

You can also remove the upper or lower case letters from your class by using the `i` modifier to match case independent:

```
/(\+\d+([ATGCN]+))/gi
```

Comment: You'd need to capture `(\d+)` then also, I think.

Comment: @Alexey, the OP captured the digits to use it in the quantifier, but he doesn't want it as explicit result. Since this approach is not working, I removed that group.

Comment: @Stema, thanks for the simple answer. I'll build a more complex parsing loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
my @sequences = split(/\+/, $string);

for my $seq (@sequences) {
    my($bases) = $seq =~ /([^\d]+)/;
}
```